# Shell script to check files and move them to different directory

Tags: unix, bash, shell, script

A client of us, is going to transfer the files to our server. I need to check if the files exist in that inbound directory and if they are , move them to a different directory so I can read them from my code. I need to write a shell script for this. How do I iterate through files in that inbound directory?

Answer (score 1):

Write your script around [`rsync`](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) and let it do the work. It does intelligent synchronization of files - locally or on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

make a cronjob which does this:

```
find INBOUND -type f -exec mv '{}' THEOTHERPLACE ';'
```

the tricky part is to find out, if a file is not yet finished (eg, someone is still uploading). you could play around with `fuse` to find out, if someone is still writing to a file and ignore that file (for now).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to check they are not in use...

```
find INBOUND -type f -mmin 10 -exec mv '{}' THEOTHERPLACE ';'
```

-mmin n : file's data was last modified n minites ago